# call RoomDB operations without viewmodelScope and runBlocking or GlobalScope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

So I have to call some functions from the **MyDao** class and that has to be done inside a scope, but I don't have a **viewmodel** implementation present and I don't want to use GlobalScope or **runBlocking**.

How can I call the room operations from the background?

Eg. need to call this from the Wrapper class.

```
myDB!!.myDao().getMyData()
```

This **getMyData()** function returns MyData, I need to take care of that too.

but without any scope, it will give an error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This should help - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Comment: Even if you're using **ViewModel**, you should never use ```GlobalScope``` and ```runBlocking``` to launch your **coroutine** or to create a **CoroutineScope**

Comment: That's not gonna help in this case.

Comment: yeah, that's why this question!

Comment: Please go through the documentation. You have other **scopes** such as **lifecycleScope**. You can use that. Make sure to add the **required dependecies**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Scope

If you are in the viewModel you could use

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    myDB!!.myDao().getMyData()
}
```

But if you are in Activity or Fragment

```
lifecycleScope.launch { 
    myDB!!.myDao().getMyData()
        
}
```

And of course `getMyData()` must be **`suspend`**

For more info check out [this android article](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Comment: I'm calling it from a wrapper class, so using none of them. This wont help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wrapper class doesn't have a scope associated with it.

In that case, you can create a scope using `CoroutineScope()` function.

You can create a custom **scope** in your wrapper using,
`val ioScope= CoroutineScope(Dispatcher.IO);`

Comment: this does not help in my case, since I have to return data.

Comment: When you create a scope, your scope returns a **job**. If you want to use  **returned data** from your function, create a **nullable variable** and asign it with the data from your returned funcion inside the scope.

Comment: I've tried that, but in that case, we reach to return statement first and then inside scope.

Comment: Please put your wrapper class and behavior you expect